# How to write a NodeJS module that is usable from command-line and as a module?

Tags: node.js, module, command-line-arguments, require

I have a module that expects to be called from the command line, so it processes command-line arguments using `yargs`, and fails with a help message if it isn't provided any.

But I'd also like this module to be called from other NodeJS modules (using `gulp`). If I simply `require(./mymodule)`, it will attempt to parse command line arguments and fail.

One obvious solution is to put the command-line bit in a separate module which wrappers the main module. Are there others? Is there a common pattern?

EDIT

And is there a naming convention to distinguish the wrapper from the main module?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just use a wrapper script for the command line invocation, as you alluded to.  I feel like thats the more common pattern in nodeland.  But if I HAD to solve this problem I'd probably do something like this.

```
var path = require('path');
var fileBase = path.parse(__filename).base;

var lib = {
    run: function() {
        console.log('my lib is running');
    }
};

module.exports = lib;


// assuming your file is not named node.js or gulp.js
// this will execute the module only when its invoked directly via the command line 
// eg node ./path/to/mylib
process.argv.reduce(function(opts, arg) {
    if (opts || arg[0] === '-') return true;
    if (path.parse(arg).base === fileBase) {
        lib.run();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. Question I probably should have included: is there a naming convention for the module and its command line wrapper?

Comment: interesting question.... its somewhat conventional to leave off the `.js` when the js code is intended to be used as an executable then add a hashbang at the top `#!/usr/bin/env node`  of the file.
if you look in your ./node_modules/.bin directory you'll sometimes see js executables in there that follow this pattern... such as `gulp` or `knex` or whatever